# Show all comments in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio

I draw object in Visio 2016 and add some comments. But comments not visible as default.

[image]

Is it possible somehow tell system to show all comments?

Answer (score 2):

Type "Show Comments" in the "Tell me what you want to do" and click on "Show Comments" option. This will open the Comments Task Pane, where you'd be able to see all comments.